# Alter font used for every pin in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In some scatter plots I'm producing, I want to label each point using a pin. I achieve that by adding `\node` elements after the `\addplot` but within the `axis` environment, and using the `pin` property:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates
      {
        (1,1)
        (2,2.5)
        (3,2.9)
        (4,4.1)
      };
    \node[pin = texta] at (axis cs:1,1) {};
    \node[pin = \small textb] at (axis cs:2,2.5) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To adjust the font of a single pin, I can simply put in the appropriate command, as shown in the demo. However, I'd ideally like to set the style for all 'pin text' in one go. However, my attempts using `every pin`, `every pin edge` and so on have failed entirely. Simply doing

```
\tikzset{font = \small}
```

fails as all of the text is now drawn until the end of the axis, meaning this 'escapes' and affects the axis labels, too. So far, the best I can come up with is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{Pin/.style = {font = \small}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates
      {
        (1,1)
        (2,2.5)
        (3,2.9)
        (4,4.1)
      };
    \node[pin = {[Pin]texta}] at (axis cs:1,1) {};
    \node[pin = {[Pin]textb}] at (axis cs:2,2.5) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which does move the detail into one place but still requires repetitive use of the style for each pin.

Is there a 'cleaner' way to do what I want? (If not, that would also be a valid answer.)

Comment: `\tikzset{every pin/.style = {font = \tiny}}` works fine here.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. OK, must have messed up in my testing :-) I'll leave the question as it might be handy for someone, I guess

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use something like

```
every pin/.append style={font=\small}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{
every pin/.append style={font=\small}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates
      {
        (1,1)
        (2,2.5)
        (3,2.9)
        (4,4.1)
      };
    \node[pin = texta] at (axis cs:1,1) {};
    \node[pin = textb] at (axis cs:2,2.5) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]